# Can we show different actions on notification on Apple watch than on phone app?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

We have a couple notifications in our iOS app that have actions (initiate a call and open another iOS application on phone) that don't translate well when showing on the Apple Watch.

I've looked to see about a specific `UIUserNotificationActionContext` for the watch (instead of using default or minimal) and I've also looked to see if I can change the category when the notification is fired in my custom notification interface controller (Dynamic Interface). No luck.

I'll go down the path of a Handoff to my iOS phone app if all else fails, but that isn't optimal since many users won't understand the Swipe Up/Unlock steps of Handoff.

I'd rather just hide those buttons for now and wait to see if iOS9 has more open support.

Comment: I can't help you with your issue (as I don't know much about iOS or the Apple Watch), but I suggest that you post some relevant details (screenshots/source code) and add some specific questions. This might help others get some more info and provide more concrete answers.

Comment: TY MasterAM.  I will add those details in the future.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot have different actions, they all must be defined in the parent app's appDelegate with `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` and `UIMutableUserNotificationCategory` and therefore shared with the watch app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have found this to be true as well